# Getting empty <tbody> when requests.get()

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-table, python-requests

I'm trying to scrap data from an HTML table on this page https://www.letrot.com/stats/fiche-cheval/enjoy-the-game/ZGJaZgYEBQMW/courses/dernieres-performances#sub_sub_menu_fichecheval , but I get an empty tbody `<tbody></tbody>.`

I managed to retrieve another table from the same site but I don't understand why, with the same commands, I can't retrieve this table. Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

url_perf = 'https://www.letrot.com/stats/fiche-cheval/enjoy-the-game/ZGJaZgYEBQMW/courses/dernieres-performances#sub_sub_menu_fichecheval'

response_perf = requests.get(url_perf, headers=headers)
html_perf = response_perf.text
soup_perf = BeautifulSoup(html_perf, 'html.parser')

last_perf_body = soup_perf.find('tbody')
print(last_perf_body)
```

That returns the following:

```
<tbody>
</tbody>
```

So, how can I retrieve the content of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load the table to pandas DataFrame you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# the 'ZGJaZgYEBQMW' is from the base URL
api_url = "https://www.letrot.com/stats/fiche-cheval/enjoy-the-game/ZGJaZgYEBQMW/courses/dernieres-performances-paginate-2?search=&lenght=1000"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0"
}

data = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(data["data"])

df["allocation"] = df["allocation"].apply(
    lambda x: BeautifulSoup(x, "html.parser").div.text
)
df = df.apply(lambda x: [BeautifulSoup(str(v), "html.parser").text for v in x])

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
             dateCourse                              prix allocation dateCourseRaw     rang       nomCheval ferrure   reduction              nomDriver             nomHippodrome    nomEntraineur corde categorie specialite distance piste depart avisEntraineur video tracking avisEntraineurImg
0   2022-12-07 07/12/22         PRIX DE VILLERS COTTERETS   22 950 €    2022-12-07   000011  ENJOY THE GAME       3  11161'11"6  GELORMINIG. GELORMINI                 VINCENNES  BONDOH.E. BONDO     G        CC          A    2 100    GP    AUT              2                               \n
1   2022-11-24 24/11/22               PRIX DE LA CAMARGUE        0 €    2022-11-24   000088  ENJOY THE GAME       3  11421'14"2  GELORMINIG. GELORMINI                 VINCENNES  BONDOH.E. BONDO     G        CC          A    2 850    GP      -              2                               \n
2   2022-10-22 22/10/22  PRIX DE LA PORTE D'AUBERVILLIERS   22 950 €    2022-10-22   000011  ENJOY THE GAME       3  11261'12"6  GELORMINIG. GELORMINI                   ENGHIEN  BONDOH.E. BONDO     G        CC          A    2 150     -    AUT              2                               \n
3   2022-10-03 03/10/22                 PRIX DE LA BOURSE   19 800 €    2022-10-03   000011  ENJOY THE GAME       3  11201'12"0  GELORMINIG. GELORMINI                   ENGHIEN  BONDOH.E. BONDO     G        DD          A    2 150     -    AUT              2                               \n
4   2022-09-22 22/09/22           PRIX DE MEHUN SUR YEVRE    8 260 €    2022-09-22   000033  ENJOY THE GAME       3  11121'11"2  GELORMINIG. GELORMINI                 VINCENNES  BONDOH.E. BONDO     G        BB          A    2 100    GP    AUT              2                               \n
5   2022-09-02 02/09/22                     PRIX LAMPETIA      510 €    2022-09-02   000077  ENJOY THE GAME       3  11421'14"2  GELORMINIG. GELORMINI                 VINCENNES  BONDOH.E. BONDO     G        CC          A    2 700    GP      -              2                               \n
6   2022-08-20 20/08/22                     PRIX DE MOLAY   20 700 €    2022-08-20   000011  ENJOY THE GAME       3  11101'11"0        RAFFINE. RAFFIN                 VINCENNES  BONDOH.E. BONDO     G        EE          A    2 100    GP    AUT              2                               \n
7   2022-08-11 11/08/22            PRIX DE LA HAUTE-SAONE    3 680 €    2022-08-11   000044  ENJOY THE GAME       3  11291'12"9  GELORMINIG. GELORMINI                   ENGHIEN  BONDOH.E. BONDO     G        EE          A    2 150     -    AUT              2                               \n
8   2022-07-07 07/07/22           PRIX LES BRUYERES CARRE   12 600 €    2022-07-07   000011  ENJOY THE GAME       3  11351'13"5  GELORMINIG. GELORMINI                   LISIEUX  BONDOH.E. BONDO     D        EE          A    2 675     -    AUT              2                               \n
9   2022-06-06 06/06/22        PRIX DE LA COTE ATLANTIQUE      540 €    2022-06-06   000066  ENJOY THE GAME       3  11501'15"0   FRECELLECL. FRECELLE  CHATELAILLON-LA ROCHELLE  BONDOH.E. BONDO     G        DD          A    2 625     -      -              2                               \n
10  2022-05-14 14/05/22                 PRIX DE CAMBREMER    1 500 €    2022-05-14   000055  ENJOY THE GAME       3  11301'13"0            LAMYA. LAMY                      CAEN  BONDOH.E. BONDO     D        CC          A    2 200     -    AUT              2                               \n
11  2022-04-29 29/04/22                       PRIX SIRONE    1 020 €    2022-04-29   000066  ENJOY THE GAME       3  11281'12"8            LAMYA. LAMY  VINCENNES (A MAUQUENCHY)  BONDOH.E. BONDO     G        CC          A    2 150     -    AUT              2                               \n
12  2022-04-21 21/04/22                  PRIX DE BOULOGNE      440 €    2022-04-21   000077  ENJOY THE GAME       3  11321'13"2            LAMYA. LAMY                   ENGHIEN  BONDOH.E. BONDO     G        DD          A    2 150     -    AUT              2                               \n
13  2022-03-13 13/03/22                  PRIX DE SYRACUSE        0 €    2022-03-13  00030DA  ENJOY THE GAME       3      9'99"9  GELORMINIG. GELORMINI            CAGNES-SUR-MER  BONDOH.E. BONDO     G        EE          A    2 700     -    AUT              2                               \n
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! Could you explain me what's the difference between your url and mine? And doe the headers influence the result?

Comment: @GWild99S The page loads the data from different URL via JavaScript, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. You can open Web Developer Tools -> Network tab and you will see the URL there. You have to set `User-Agent` HTTP header, otherwise the server refuses to send the data.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly where to find it in the Network Tab?

Comment: @GWild99S In Firefox press `Ctrl+Shift+I` and then click on `Network` tab.

Comment: It's good, I finally find it, thank you very much! @Andrej Kesely